# Titan mode in battlefield

Tags: battlefield-series

Is Titan Mode available in more recent versions of BattleField (other than BF 2142) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like **no**. Considering that Battlefield 2142 is the only BF set in the future, it'd be hard to expect a battle of massive flying warships in games set in modern times or even in the past.

No game that came after BF 2142 contained even a similar mechanic to the Titan mode. They mostly focused on Conquest and Rush.